# Adding to a cells value based on two other cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm wondering how I would go about adding to a cell based on two other cells.

For example, I'm creating a Google Sheets document to track profit & loss on certain things in an online game I play.

I'll try to explain this as best as possible.

If cell `B71` is `equal to` the `string` in cell `B7`, increase the value in cell `D71` `equal to` the number in cell `D7`.
*However*, the values will need to be compared to various other things depending on the item required.
For example, the string in cell `B7` might change depending on what specific type of item is needed for that day as it does change daily.
I have cells near the bottom of the sheet which list the different type of item which will show the total amount of items used in that month.

I've tried to explain this a little better as requested below

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that keeps track of the quantity of a specific item I use in a game for a daily task. This task can be done daily, and to keep track of profit & loss, I have created a spreadsheet to keep track of this.

So, each day, there are three different types of items (runes) that can be used in the machine to create an item called 'Vis Wax'. As Runes are cheap, creating the vis wax can generate a good profit. (I love working with data, hense the spreadsheet.
[image]

The image above shows what a daily section looks like. I input each type of rune (has to be 3), input the quantity used and the amount each rune is worth to create the total cost under *Total*.
Further down below, this table has been created
[image: Quantity of Runes]

This will keep track of each rune and the amount used during that month.

So with that said, I'm looking for a solution so that if Air rune is entered in ANY of them slots with the QUANTITY used, it'll update that table accordinly (as well as the other runes that are used too). I've tried nested IF statements, but don't seem to have any luck. With the amount of checks that seem to be happening, I can't seem to find a working solution. As Air Rune might be in slot 1 one day, then slot 3 the next day. So it seems each cell in the Quantity Table will need to compare EACH cell in the daily section, to each rune type that can be used.

Hopefully that has explained it a little better.

Spreadsheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYLpZJ46IpNk52gxMoJOIZsOCWToLkC4FF83RBncCf0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Your scenario seems complex but your problem is simple. As you say you could have the following scheme:
`B71` any string,
`B7` list of different strings (data validation),
`D71` = `if(B71=B7, D7, 0)`,
`D7` value to be taken by `D71`

Note that a cell cannot increase its value every time two other cells are the same because when they are the same they are always the same and it cannot increase infinitely.


Try to explain better your scenario, the variables that appear and give a complete example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I have adjusted the post above to try and explain my situation a little better. @fullfine, I used your example above and it worked as intended, but I'm not too sure how I would go about using that against 14 different types.

Comment: George, we also all love working with spreadsheets, and it would make it a bit easier for most of us to help on your problem if you shared a copy of your sheet.  That way we don't all need to try to recreate it ourselves, trying to match your images, and then test out our tentative solutions.

Comment: Your sheet structure sounds a bit confusing to me.  If your "Totals for the Month" table is near the bottom of the sheet, do you have a daily section, like your first image, repeated about 30 times down from the top of the sheet?  Or going across?  I assume the daily sections are filled in manually each day with the rune types, and their amounts...?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYLpZJ46IpNk52gxMoJOIZsOCWToLkC4FF83RBncCf0/edit?usp=sharing - Link to the Spreadsheet

Comment: Added a link to the spreadsheet at the end of the post.

Comment: Could you also include some sample data in your sheet, so we don't all need to enter our own test data?  Also, is there a formula for the amount of VIS WAX produced each day, and its value, based on the runes used and their amounts, or do we have to pull those actual amounts from each days mini-table as well?

Comment: I have included some test data for the first 4 days. All of the cells which are left White are cells which the values need entering manually as these are gathered from the game itself. The cells in grey are calculated automatically. I've added the value of the total amount of each rune in the table below just by doing a simple =CELL+CELL formula. But I want that table to comapre it with what has been entered daily and fill in that table automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a different structure and take all the data from one day in one column, something like this:
[image: Vis Wax Tracker]

In this way you will be able to extend the days keeping the formulas in a really simple way. Below, I will explain some useful formulas that you can use to lighten your work:

- Day: `=text(DAY(B2),"dddd")`
- Rune type: Check [Data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to create a drop-down list of your rune types

For counting how many runes have you used you can use [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en) function. It returns the sum of a range depending on multiple criteria. In your case, you need apply it three time per rune, as you can have the same rune in three different places. You see it with the following image:
[image: SUMIFS]

The formula is: `=SUMIFS($B$8:$H$8,$B$7:$H$7,A25) + SUMIFS($B$12:$H$12,$B$11:$H$11,A25) + SUMIFS($B$16:$H$16,$B$15:$H$15,A25)`. In this way you only need to write it once and you can fill the rest of the runes just dragging the mouse. If you need more days just change the column `H` with the last column that you want to take.

I assume that with all this information you can also keep track of your monthly statics easily. I suggest you to create a different sheet for each month.

I hope that my answer was useful, let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score -1):

George, I agree with @fullfine, your data structure does not seem ideal for data analysis.  And it doesn't seem that efficient for data entry either, with the sideways scrolling (at least on my screen).

But I recognise that you might not want to change it, perhaps having specific reasons for that layout, and having invested time in it.  So I offer this formula as an alternative, which basically pulls the needed cells from your existing sheet, and comes up with the totals you'll need.

```
=QUERY(QUERY({B7:D9;G7:I9;L7:N9;Q7:S9;V7:X9;AA7:AC9;AF7:AH9;
              B20:D22;G20:I22;L20:N22;Q20:S22;V20:X22;AA20:AC22;AF20:AH22;
              B33:D35;G33:I35;L33:N35;Q33:S35;V33:X35;AA33:AC35;AF33:AH35;
              B46:D48;G46:I48;L46:N48;Q46:S48;V46:X48;AA46:AC48;AF46:AH48;
              B59:D61;G59:I61;L59:N61},
           "select Col1, Col2, Col3*Col2 where Col1 <>'' order by Col1 label Col3*Col2 '' ",0),
     "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '', sum(Col3) '' ",0)
```

[image]

The same formula can be used for each month, since it always totals all 31 days, even if the month has fewer days.

For your Rune table in the Statistics sheet, you only need the firsts two columns, so you could delete the "sum(Col3)" from the last select statement.

For your smaller financial table, you would take the sum of the Col3 produced by the above formula, ie. the total value of all the runes used.  A similar formula would be used to collect the count of the wax produced, its value, and the profit/loss for each day.  This would let you complete the financial table.

If you do decide to go with this approach, and want any help with completing the tables, or the formulas, please share your sheet so "anyone can edit it", to make it easier for me to assist you.

Comment: Note that currently my formula only lists Runes that have been used that month.  If you want all Runes to be listed, with zero values for the Runes that weren't used, that could be done as well.